# Truffle config not matching web3 infos

Tags: web3js, truffle

At `truffle.js` I set the account to the third ganache's account

[image]

Then I run truffle console and coinbase was set to the first account and defaultAccount to undefined. Not only that, I've tried to change the coinbase to the second account and it also didn't work

[image]

The most interesting part is: I ran a function from a contract that stores a `mapping(address=>A) v` (let's say A is a contract and v the mapping name). The expected outcome from `v(web3.eth.coinbase)` would be the contract's address, but there was the empty address. And when I ran `v(web3.eth.address[2])`, there was the contract's address, meaning I just have to trust the truffle's config.

But I'd like to solve this anyways, for presentation's sake

Answer (score 0):

From the [web3.eth.coinbase](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcoinbase)  documentation:

> This property is read only and returns the coinbase address where the mining rewards go to.

To modify the miner address you have to call [`miner.setEtherbase`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#miner_setetherbase)

Can't help with the issue with your mapping without access to your contracts and the deployment scripts.